# How to get full default route url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to avoid get "/"(root path),I want to get the full path like home/Index(as my default route)?

```
var redirectTo = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; 
if (redirectTo.Equals("/")) 
{ 
VirtualPathData vp = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, "Default", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" })); 
redirectTo = vp.VirtualPath; 
}
```

or

```
    UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);;
    redirectTo = u.RouteUrl("Default", ((Route)RouteTable.Routes["Default"]).Defaults);
```

but all of above is not working. thanks!

Comment: Without seeing your routing table it is hard to say what the problem is (and why you are using such code instead of Url.Action and similar helpers...

Comment: Are you asking how you can make the routing to only work if we specify full path (home/index) instead of just root path ("/")??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can be used in order to get the default path in general cases:

```
var route = ((Route)RouteTable.Routes["Default"]).Defaults;
var url = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", route["controller"], route["action"]);
```

In case of special RouteMaps the format string ( /{0}/{1} ) should be changed.